# In JS, what value do I supply to the namespace argument of hasAttributeNS() and getAttributeNS() to indicate "no namespace"?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm having trouble finding a specification of `hasAttributeNS()` and `getAttributeNS()` that tells me what to supply for the first argument for the case of "no namespace" attributes. Empirically it seems that "" doesn't work and that null does, but that's just with one implementation and I've no idea if I can safely rely on it.

A pointer to a specification would be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html):

> DOM Level 2 doesn't perform any URI normalization or canonicalization. The URIs given to the DOM are assumed to be valid (e.g., characters such as whitespaces are properly escaped), and no lexical checking is performed. Absolute URI references are treated as strings and compared literally. How relative namespace URI references are treated is undefined. To ensure interoperability only absolute namespace URI references (i.e., URI references beginning with a scheme name and a colon) should be used. Note that because the DOM does no lexical checking, the empty string will be treated as a real namespace URI in DOM Level 2 methods. **Applications must use the value null as the namespaceURI** parameter for methods if they wish to have no namespace.

The [hasAttributeNs](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-ElHasAttrNS):

```
hasAttributeNS introduced in DOM Level 2  
    Returns true when an attribute with a given local name and namespace URI is specified on this element or has a default value, false otherwise. HTML-only 
    DOM implementations do not need to implement this method.  

    Parameters  
        namespaceURI of type DOMString  
            The namespace URI of the attribute to look for.
        localName of type DOMString
            The local name of the attribute to look for.
```